# IBM's Docker Informix Innovator C 14.10.FC4IE only allows 8GB DBSpace

Tags: docker, db2, ibm-cloud, informix

In the 2nd minor revision of 14.10 innovator C, the dbspace limit was increased from 8GB to 50GB. However when you pull down **ibmcom/informix-innovator-c:14.10.FC4IE** directly from IBM...

The max dbspace it creates it 8GB even though the onconfig is set to 50GB

Seems like a big oversight on IBM's behalf and I would rather not want to handcraft my own Informix container.

Does anyone have any insight on this?

Thanks

Comment: I started a discussion internally on 2020-10-16 trying to chase down what is behind this.  It appears your observation is correct.  It was partially due to some internal edition branding changes.  I don't have an ETA for a resolution, nor details on what the resolution is.

Comment: The short-term workaround is to install an earlier version with the bigger limits.